# css design look fileupload

Tags: php, html, css

i just try do a design which makes fileupload looks like it 
[this is what i try to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shwMB.png)

which every image upload appears on the website as u see in the image 
and makes the fileupload button ( upload) at the middle of the page

my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>upload -imgserv</title>
<style>
footer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/AuE2B9T7Q5mx5rXd0P-ZXA.png" alt="logo" style="width:100px;height:90px;">
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
image selector :<input type="file" name="image"><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
</form>
<p><a href="https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/money/">donate</a> to keep us alive</a>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_tmp_name= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    @$desc = $_POST['desc'];
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name,"uploads/$image_name");
echo "<img src='uploads/$image_name' width='400' height='250'><br>";
echo "your image : ";
}
?>

<footer>
<a href="tos.html" class="bottomLinks">terms of service</a> - <a href="faq.html" class="bottomLinks">faq</a> - <a href="contact.html" class="bottomLinks">contact us</a> 
<span id="footerRight" class="copyright footerFont"><strong>@imgserv v1.3 </strong></span>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are your problems here?

Comment: the css of the web wants to looks like what in the image !  https://i.stack.imgur.com/shwMB.png